# Distributive function of the sum of two measurable functions.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mu)$ a measurable space and let $f,g:X \to \mathbb{C}$ complex measurable functions. We define the Distributive function of $f$ by
$$D_f(\lambda) = \mu(\{x : |f(x)| > \lambda \}) $$
I'm having trouble to prove that for any $t,s >0$ we have
$$D_{f+g}(t+s) \leq D_f(t) + D_g(s) $$
some help or hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D_{f+g}(t+s) \leq \mu(\{x: |f(x)| \geq t \textrm{   or    } |g(x)| \geq s\}) \leq D_f(t)+D_g(s)$

Here the second inequality is due to union bound. The first one is since $|f+g| \geq t +s$, either $|f|\geq t$ or $|g| \geq s$.

Comment: I think that $|f+g|\geq t+s$ does not implies $|f|\geq t$ or $|g|\geq s$.

Comment: @Inzit It does! Prove by contradiction: if $|f| <t$ and $|g| <s$ then $|f+g|<t+s$.

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't see it.